# javascript cant get the right variable value from a given argument

Tags: javascript, variables, arguments

Hi,

I have this JavaScript code

```
function mycode(con) {
 var date1="feb-9";
 var date2="feb-11";
 var date3="feb-20";
 var getdate = con;
    document.write(getdate);

}
```

This code is supposed to display a specific date depending on the given argument like below:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">mycode("date1");</script>
```

It wont work because all I get is "date1" instead of the value for that variable which should be "feb-9".

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: your calling and called functions is different

Comment: Sorry, I corrected that.

Comment: Why do you have `date1` 3 times? Also, what you are receiving is a string representation of a variable name and you want variable value.

Comment: Have you considered using an array instead? That way you wouldn't need "date1", just 0

Comment: The answer has already been given, thank you anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't create a dynamic variable that way. Use an object. Then you can use `[]` notation for variable property names

```
function mycode(con) {
    var dates = {
        date1: "feb-9",
        date2: "feb-11",
        date3: "feb-20"
    };
    alert(dates[con]);    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are simply printing the string

Try this

```
function mycode(con) {
var date ={
 'date1': "feb-9",
 'date2': "feb-11"
}
var getdate = "not found";
    for( var k in date){
    if(k == con){
        getdate = date[k]
    }
  }     
  alert(getdate);  
}
mycode("date1");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/